# Select count same column but no NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got this table:

> ```
> id    akce                    text    x       y        z      a       year
>
> 61    FF1231-00               Bob     NULL    NULL    58      NULL    2014
> 62    FF1231-00               Alice   NULL    NULL    57      NULL    2014
> 57    FF1231-00               1/2 SWC 2       20      NULL    NULL    2014
> 58    FF1231-00               1/3 SWC 3       5       NULL    NULL    2014
> 59    FF1231-00               Jim     NULL    NULL    57      NULL    2014
> ```

Now I'm trying to achieve to find how many results having column `z` not NULL at SUM match

`table.id = table.z WHERE table.z is NOT NULL`

> ```
> id    akce                    text    x       y        z      a       year
>
> 57    FF1231-00               1/2 SWC 2       20      NULL    2       2014
> 58    FF1231-00               1/3 SWC 3       5       NULL    1       2014
> ```

I tried to do following

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.text, T1.z, T1.akce, T2.[text], (SELECT COUNT(T1.z) where T1.z IS NOT NULL Group by T1.z)
FROM ubytov T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov T2
    ON T1.z = T2.id
    WHERE T1.akce='FF1231-00' AND T1.z IS NULL
```

But got this exception:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Can you guys please help me to achieve that result?

Thanks in advance and thanks for your time.

EDIT:
This query according to Fabio answer gives me desired result:

```
SELECT t.id
, t.akce
, t.text
, t.x
, t.y
, t.z
, qnt.Quantity
FROM ubytov t 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(q.z) AS Quantity FROM Ubytov
q WHERE q.z = t.id) qnt WHERE t.z is NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want to know how much same `ID` found from `z` column
Try `CROSS APPLY` (query from [SQL Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70e9d/1))

```
SELECT t.ID
, t.Akce
, t.x
, t.y
, t.z
, qnt.Quantity
FROM Test t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(q.ID) AS Quantity FROM Test q WHERE q.z = t.ID) qnt
```

If you want remove rows with `Quantity = 0` from result,
then change `OUTER APPLY` to `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: thank you, this helped me a lot, if you wish, see my edit how the final query looks like in my case. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your edit work fine, if you want only results with `z = NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.text, T1.z, T1.akce, T2.[text], 
(SELECT COUNT(T3.z) FROM ubytov T3 where T3.z IS NOT NULL)
FROM ubytov T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubytov T2
    ON T1.z = T2.id
    WHERE T1.akce='FF1231-00' AND T1.z IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I'm getting in each row result `3` which is not correct. This query counts both rows together. If you wish see Fabio's answer he applied `OUTER APPLY` in the query.